# Dotted border appears as “solid” in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an input field inside a tbody tr.

I made its border dotted when hovering (with CSS). It works well on Firefox, but, it does not work in Chrome.

In Chrome the border line is being shown as "dotted" ONLY if it is 3px or more. If it's smaller, like in the example code (2px), it's shown as "soild".

Any ideas on how to make it work in 2px or less?

```css
input[name="task"].form-control:hover{
       background-color: #f0f2f5;
       border: 2px dotted lightgray !important;
       border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb" >
            <thead id="table-header">
                <tr class="tr-header"">
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Task</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                  <!--task-->
                  <td class="tasks-cell">
                      <input type="text" name="task" class="form-control
                      task-input" value = "test test">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: try `background-clip: padding-box;`

Comment: why? the code works fine as is in a chrome browser.  It goes to dots on hover

Comment: The on hover outline shows as dotted for me with Mac Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: 1px dotted border works for me on all browsers I tested (Chrome, FF, Safari, IE 11, Edge). I doubt it's a browser related issue but your monitor. What's your monitor size and resolution now?

Comment: there's an extra " here: <tr class="tr-header"">

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work...

Comment: @noob  34 inch, 2752x1152

Comment: can you please try adding `outline: none`  to the hover section and please let me know whether it works or not

Comment: OK Maybe it might be something related to your screen resolution or something, its working fine on my laptop